# Get information between two different times Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime

I am making a modification to an Oracle Query, where I need to get the information found from the query date and minute up to 30 minutes ago.
For example, I made the query at 16:35, so I need it to show me the information found from 16:05 to 16:35.
I did something like this, but I don't have the result I need.
Also, how can I make it find everything loaded with current date? This is what I have done with no result

```
AND FV.FEC_CAR = dateadd(minute,-30,getdate()) ORDER BY F.N_FILE DESC
```

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

`dateadd` and `getdate` aren't valid in Oracle's SQL dialect.  That looks like SQL Server syntax but it probably works in some other database as well.

In Oracle, you'd do

```
fv.fec_car > sysdate - interval '30' minute
```

or

```
fv.fec_car > sysdate - 30/24/60
```

I find the `interval` syntax far clearer personally

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can understand and interpret, you need to see the data at a point in the past before applying some modification to your table. This case,

```
SELECT *
  FROM tab AS OF TIMESTAMP SYSTIMESTAMP - INTERVAL '30' MINUTE
```

*might be* used to see the values of half an hour before modification if **undo_retention** parameter's value of your database is big enough(*without forgetting that it does not guarantee to return a result even if the value is big enough*)